# Is it possible to support visitor comments in Docusaurus?

Tags: docusaurus

I'm building a website using [Docusaurus 2](https://v2.docusaurus.io).

My website will contain docs and blogs. I wonder if it is possible to let visitors comment below an article?

I guess, if we support comments, we need an authentication system for the website too.

If the native Docusaurus does not support this, Is there any plugin to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely. You can swizzle the doc pages and embed your own Disqus social plugin/Facebook comments plugin.

See this website for an example - https://www.banli17.com/docs/f2e/html/index/ of adding comments on pages via GitHub, which is a very cool idea! (Update Jul 5, 2020: the link is broken).

Find a tutorial here - https://coderhackers.com/blog/2020/02/29/how-to-add-forum-to-docusaurus (thanks @kirtan403)

Comment: The link is broken. Any other example of doing it?

Comment: https://www.coderhackers.com/blog/2020/02/29/how-to-add-forum-to-docusaurus/ This will help.

Comment: It looks like all the links are broken.

Comment: Links are broken

Comment: This link may help: https://happyreact.com/blog/feedback-widget-in-docusaurus
It's my blog on how to add a feedback widget at the bottom of every page in docusaurus.

Answer (score 2):

You can use swizzle to extract the component attached at the bottom of every page. It is `DocItemFooter` and here is a documentation for swizzling: https://docusaurus.io/docs/swizzling

I made a post about how to add a feedback widget in docusaurus here: https://happyreact.com/blog/feedback-widget-in-docusaurus
It's not about adding a comment but it's a simple walkthrough how to use swizzle and add custom component that is attached to every page

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can swizzle a wrapper e.g. `BlogPostItemWrapper` for your blog posts using `Giscus` commenting system.

Check my [blog post](https://m19v.github.io/blog/how-to-add-giscus-to-docusaurus) where you can **test it live** and find a step-by-step description of how to add Giscus, a commenting system powered by GitHub Discussions, to a static website generated by Docusaurus.

Comment: I think giscus only allows only github users to add comments? There is no oauth2 capability yet.

Comment: From Giscus documentation: "To comment, visitors must authorize the giscus app to post on their behalf using the GitHub OAuth flow." I.e. You do authorize via GitHub.